# Why do we say that probability of an individual event in a continuous distribution is 0?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, philosophy

So I understand that the probability a<x<b is the definite integral from a to b of tye probability density function and that makes sense.  If we use that same definition to define the probability that x is equal to some value, then we would get 0.  And yet, it doesn’t really make sense to say that probability of something is 0 if it’s still possible for it to happen.  Furthermore, this introduces the paradox that adding up a bunch of zero probabilities somehow gives us a total property of 1.  You can’t add up zero things and get a non zero result.  That makes no sense.  However, you can add up an arbitrarily large number of arbitrarily tiny pieces and and get a non zero real number result.  This is precisely what integration does.  So why don’t we just say that the probability of a single event in a continuous distribution is simply undefined?  i.e. Why not define the probability function as p(a<x<b)=integral from a to b of P(x), such that a≠b, and p(a<x<b) is undefined such that a=b, where P(x) is the probability density function?
I suppose, to an extent, this is just a matter of semantics: We can certainly redefine the word “probability” so that the sum of the individual probabilies doesn’t have to equal 1, but instead the integral of the probability density function must be equal to 1, but what’s the point?  The way I see it, it doesn’t really make sense to ask the probability of a specific event when we’re dealing with a continuous probability distribution and I don’t see how it would be useful.  So why not just leave those probabilities undefined?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/273382/how-can-the-probability-of-each-point-be-zero-in-continuous-random-variable

Comment: What would be the profit of this (i.e. stating that the measure of sets that under the current definition give value $0$ will be "undefined" under the new definition)? It looks a bit like going back to the Roman age where number $0$ was not practicized. It seems to me that the only profit is that your intuition might be less harmed. Your view on what integration does seems to lack the concept of taking limits (there it distinguishes itself from "adding up"). Also it smells like Riemann integration but in probability theory people work mostly with Lebesgue integration.

Comment: I'll suppose that $X$ is a continuous random variable. Nobody claims anywhere that if $E \subset \mathbb R$ then $P(X \in E) = \sum_{x \in E} P(X = x)$. So the paradox you mentioned is avoided simply by not making that claim. (It's not clear how the sum on the right would be defined when $E$ is uncountable, by the way.) What is claimed is that $P(X \in E) = \int_E f_X(x) \, dx$, where $f_X$ is a probability density function for $X$, but there is nothing paradoxical about that.

Comment: Why don't you just redefine the word "possible" so that probability zero events are not possible?

Comment: drhab I understand the limit definition of integration.  However, the way I learned it, one of the defining properties of PROBABILITY functions is that their SUM must be equal to 1.  I was just reading about probability densities in quantum mechanics from my professor’s powerpoint and it also specifically said this.  I also remember a video about probability densities by 3blue1brown that specifically talked them in those terms.  I’m fine with changing the definition of probability, but it seems people are still using the sum definition even in the context of probability distributions.

Comment: What you are stating in your comment is correct if we are dealing with a so-called *probability mass function* which is actually a density wrt the so-called counting measure. In that case "sum" is fine. Things change if we are dealing with what we call probability density functions. Again densities but now wrt the Lebesgue measure. Then the term "sum" can only informally be practicized. We are dealing however with integrals and the demand is now $\int f(x)dx=1$ instead of $\sum_xf(x)=1$. I would say that a sum a special integral and an integral is a generalization of sum.

Comment: You might be interested in this YouTube video by 3blue1brown: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZA4JkHKZM50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll rephrase your concerns for a slightly different, but very related concept: volume.

The volume of a set of points is the volume integral of 1 over the given set. Using this definition, the volume of a single point in space is 0. Yet it doesn't make sense to say that the volume of a set is 0 if there's still something in it. Furthermore, it introduces the paradox that adding up a bunch of sets with volume 0 gives a set with positive volume, since every set is just a union of sets with a single point in it.
So wouldn't it be better to just leave the volume of a point undefined?

Here, the answer should be no, a volume of 0 for point-like sets is perfectly fine. There's also no paradox here, since adding only a countable number of zeroes actually produces zero again: any countable set has volume 0. And adding an uncountable number of numbers is undefined, so the volume of uncountable sets need not be 0, since it's an *uncountable* union of sets with volume zero, so we can't just add their volumes. The closest thing to an uncountable sum we have is the integral, which actually does give us the desired non-zero volume.

There is no difference between the volume case and the probability case. And I want to stress this: the underlying concept behind volume and probability is *exactly* the same: both probability and volume are defined via so-called measures, which were specifically defined to model the behavior of volumes. Any intuition you have about volume should be carried over to probability as is, with the single exception that probability must be no larger than 1. But that has no bearing on the question wether single points should have a defined volume/probability or not.

Comment: Thanks.  My main issue is, if we’re going to define probability solely in terms of integrals, then we shouldn’t say that the SUM of all probabilities is 1.  Rather, we should say that the integral of the probability density function from must be 1.  Twice, I’ve seen educational resources explaining probability density use the word “sum” to define this aspect of probability (if we’re talking abiut discrete probabilities sums are fine of course).  That led me to believe it was the usual definition, but perhaps it was just lazy language by those two sources.

Comment: It is lazy language. The sum really only works on discrete probability spaces. But the main strength of modern probability theory is that it's no longer restricted to discrete spaces. Technically, probabilities aren't defined via integration, either. Probabilites are measures (you can look those up on wikipedia), and they require that the *measure* of the entire probability space is 1.  We can then go on to define integrals on these probability spaces, and then it turns out that the measure of a set can often be calculated via the integral over a density function. But not always.

Comment: @MikaylaEckelCifrese "Twice, I’ve seen educational resources explaining probability density use the word “sum” to define this aspect of probability" You should show an exact quote or screenshot. It sounds to me like those educational resources were simply incorrect.

Comment: @littleO, how do I share a screenshot in a comment?

Comment: You might be able to edit your question and include a screenshot there, but perhaps that requires more reputation points. Alternatively, I think you could post a screenshot somewhere else, such as on imgur, and post a link to it in a comment. If you're satisfied with these answers already and you don't feel like doing that then that's fine too, of course.